# Comando Angular 6 CLI para criar um component numa pasta expecifica

Tags: angular, front-end, angular-6, angular-cli, cli

tem algum jeito de criar um component no Angular 6 CLI expecificando em qual pasta ele deve ficar? eu pesquisei na net e encontrei o `ng g c nome-componente --module=app` mas esse é só pra expecificar que vai ficar no `app` eu tentei fazer tipo `--module=app/minha-pasta`, `--module=app\minha-pasta` e etc pra tentar expecificar em qual pasta eu quero q fique esse component mas nn consegui, alguem sabe como fazer isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim

```
ng g component minha-pasta/component --flat
```

O parametro flat serve para gerar os arquivos sem criar uma nova pasta

Answer (score -1):

abra um novo terminal integrado clicando com botão direito na pasta que deseja e após isso rode o comando

ng g(generate) c(componente) "nome do seu componente"  --skip-import (para já importar no modulo onde ele foi criado)